# Style unaligned using <md-button> with <md-icon> on a <md-table-cell> on Material VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-material

I want put the actions on the same data row, I've two actions and to do it I'm using a button and a icon as the code below.

```
    <md-table v-model="gruposDeInsumos" md-sort="codigo" md-sort-order="asc" md-card>
        <md-table-row slot="md-table-row" slot-scope="{item}">
            <md-table-cell class="item-codigo" md-label="Código" md-sort-by="codigo"> {{item.codigo}}</md-table-cell>
            <md-table-cell class="item-nome" md-label="Nome" md-sort-by="nome"> {{item.nome}}</md-table-cell>
            <md-table-cell md-label="Tipo" md-sort-by="tipo"> {{item.tipo === 'products' ? 'Produtos' : 'Serviços'}}</md-table-cell>
            <md-table-cell md-label="Ações"> 
                <md-button>
                    <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button>
                    <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-table-cell>
        </md-table-row>
    </md-table>
```

The result this is:

[image]

Like you can see, I've two lines on the same table row, this happened after I added the two actions buttons (edit and delete). So, how I fix it to make these components keeping on the same row?

Besides that, If anyone knows, How I can choose the `<md-icon>` color?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own CSS and apply a class that contains the `display: flex` property. Or you could read their documentation and use their columns syntax. They probably have some sort of classes to add columns.

Comment: I don`t know use the CSS